# How to create numeric array from a string in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab

How to create numeric array from a string in Matlab?

For example I have such a string:

```
>> str = dec2bin(7);
s = 111
```

I need the array `[1 1 1]`. How to do it?

I see `strread` function [strread](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strread.html)
but I get difficulties to use it with non-space string input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard solution is to use the solution posted by yuk,

```
a = (str == '1');
```

which produces a logical result. If you need a double,

```
a = double(str == '1');
```

or even just:

```
a = +(str == '1');
```

Perhaps the simplest looking solution is this one:

```
a = str - 48;
```

although I think the last is least obvious as to what it does. I prefer code that is easy to read and understand the purpose. That goal is best met by the second solution, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Just answered another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596849) and found  a part of it might be useful here.

You can actually convert such a string to a logical vector:

```
a = str == '1';
```

You can cast it to another type, for example `double(a)`.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, naively:

```
n = length(s);
myArray = zeros(1,n)
for i = 1:n
myArray(i) = double(s(i));
```

where "double()" is whatever the command is for changing a string element to a double precision number, if that is indeed what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is using "bitget"

```
> x = bitget(7,1:3);

> class(bitget(7,1:3))  
  ans =  

  double
```

The result is double.

Comment: Thank you very much. I don't need strings anymore ;)

Answer (score 1):

With `strread`:
`a = strread('123', '%c')`