# What is the neatest way of passing flags to a Matlab function?

Tags: matlab, argument-passing

I'm designing a function that takes as argument one structure and any number of flags. The function will contain a couple of `if`s checking whether a specific flag is set.

What is the neatest way to achieve this? I was thinking about passing the flags as separate string arguments. Is there a neater solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like using `varargin` and `ismember`:

```
function foo(arg1,arg2,varargin)

  flag1=ismember('flag1',varargin);
  flag2=ismember('flag2',varargin);
  flag3=ismember('flag3',varargin);
```

And you can call the function like that:

```
foo(a1,a2,'flag3','flag1')
```

This will activate `flag1` and `flag3`.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you can pass varargin - 
The even will be names of the flags and the odd their values (except the first)

> function Foo(st, varargin)
>
> end

Then pass values like this:

> Foo(st, 'Flag1', true, 'Flag2', false)
>   Foo(st, 'Flag3', true, 'MyFlag2', false,'MySpecialFlag',false)
>   Foo(st)

To access the variable arguments use

> varargin{2}, varargin{3},

etc..

To check whether a specific flag was passed, do

> flagNames = varargin{2:end};
>   ismember('MyFlag',flagNames  )

Comment: Is there a simple way of checking whether a specific flag was passed or not?

Answer (score 2):

Pass in a `struct` of flags:

```
options = struct(...
    'Flag1', true, ...
    'Flag2', true, ...
    'MySpecifFlag', false ...
);

Foo(st, options);
```

To get a list of all the flags that were explicitly set by the user, use `fieldnames`:

```
passedOptions = fieldnames(options);
```

This returns a cell array whose elements are strings - these strings are the flags set by the user; the `i`th element of the array is the `i`th flag set by the user.

Access the value of each flag that was set:

```
options.(passedOptions{i}) %# gets the value of the flag corresponding to passedOptions{i}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the flags as a string with 0s and 1s. The order can be fixed or you can also pass a cell array of flag names.

```
flagstr = '101'; %# string passed as argument
flaglog = flagstr=='1'; %# logical vector, can be accessed as flaglog(i)
fname = {'flag1','flag2','flag3'}; %# flag names, can be passed as argument or defined in the function
fvalue = num2cell(flaglog); %# create cell array
flags = cell2struct(fvalue, fname, 2); %# create a structure, so you can access a flag with flags.flag1
```

You need to take care to match the length of `fvalue` and `fnames`. if they are different you can either generate an error or somehow correct it (remove the extra flags or fill the absent by default value).

Answer (score 0):

`varargin` is the way to go for parsing a variable number of arbitrary input arguments. If you want somemore control over the calling syntax of the function (i.e. optional/required arguments) then I suggest looking into Matlab's [input parser](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/bresuxt-11.html).